# How to convert RealmResults<Model> to ArrayList<Model>?

Tags: java, realm, realm-list

When I use realm.where(Model.class) it returns RealmResults and list item's fields are empty. How to convert queryset to readable ArrayList or iterate over RealmResults to get actual data from objects in DB?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All fetches are lazy in Realm, and the data is never copied. So if you want to get current data from RealmResults, you must call realm.copyFromRealm(results).

```
public List<Model> getModelList() {
    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Realm realm;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<Model> results = realm
                .where(Model.class)
                .findAll();
        list.addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(results));
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You can use advanced technique since Java 1.7
`try(Realm mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()){ ... do the job...}catch(Exception e){Log.e(e)}` with this syntax at the end realm.close is invoked by itself - you have to call it explicity.

Answer (score 2):

RealmResults<E> implements the Iterable<E> interface, so you can iterate with:

```
for (E e : realmResults) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

If this does not answer the question, then please precise it and add a sample of code.

Answer (score 0):

kotlin version used in my app :

```
/**
 * convert RealmResults<Model> to ArrayList<Model>
 * REFER to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250987/how-to-convert-realmresultsmodel-to-arraylistmodel)
 * answer of [DH28](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5152885/dh28)
 *
 * @param realm realm
 * @param results RealmResults<Model> to convert
 * @return resultsList List<Model> converted
*/
fun getResultsList(
    realm: Realm,
    results: RealmResults<Model>?
): MutableList<Model> {
    val resultsList: MutableList<Model> = ArrayList()
    resultsList.addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(results!!))
    return resultsList
}
```

see also [www.mongodb.com](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/java/10.0.1/io/realm/Realm.html) method

```
copyFromRealm(Iterable<E> realmObjects)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.where(Object.class)
                .findAllAsync()
                .addChangeListener(list -> {
                   List<Object> listObjects = realm.copyFromRealm(list);
                });
```